# RabbitMQ Cluster operator - enabling MQTT plugin

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, mqtt

While using https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator I have a working setup with TLS enabled for AMQP. 
Now I would need to enable MQTT, however I donot find any example of enabling plugins with this operator.

 Can someone help with an example of enabling MQTT over RabbitMQ via the cluster operator?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Rabbit MQ Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html#additional-plugins), in order to enable mqtt plugin, we have to add the corresponding plugin name "rabbitmq_mqtt".